# Fast filter on related fields in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have 2 models in my django project.

```
ModelA(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    field1 = ...
    ~
    fieldN = ...

ModelB(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    field1 = ...
    ~
    fieldN = ...
```

Here I have one-to-mane relation A->B. Table A has around 30 different fields and 10.000+ rows and table B has around 15 and 10.000.000+ rows. I need to filter firstly by the several `ModelA` fields and then for each of the filtered `ModelA` row/object get related `ModelB` objects and filter them by several fields. After that I need to serialize them in JSON where all `ModelB` packed in one field as array.

Is it possible to perform this around the 1-3 second? If yes, what is the best approach?

I use PostgreSQL.

**EDIT:**

Now I am doing it like chain `.filter()` on simple `ModelA` fields and then iterate over resulted `QuerySet` and get set of `ModelB` for each `ModelA` instance,but i suspect, that the second part of this solution will slow down whole process, so I suppose there is a better way to do it.

Comment: It's impossible to say how long a query will take because we don't know what hardware it is running on, but if you would like assistance optimising your code it would help if you could provide some detail on what you've tried so far and what the results were like.

Comment: @ChidG I've edited my question

Answer (score 0):

It may be faster to do a query like this:

```
model_a_queryset = ModelA.objects.filter(field=whatever)
model_b_queryset = ModelB.objects.filter(a__in=model_a_queryset)
```

Because Django does lazy queryset evaulation, this will only result in one hit to the database.

As an aside, there is no need to define `id = Autofield` fields on your models. Django includes them by default.